# Load an animated SWF into a custom Flex (spark) button

Tags: flash, apache-flex, animation, flex-spark

The question is simple: How can I display an animated SWF in my custom Flex button (I am using the Spark library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your own skin class (based on `s:Skin`).
2. Add the `mx:SWFLoader` component to it, which will load your swf.
3. Apply `skinClass` style for your custom button.

Refer [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) and [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html).

Comment: Your post helped me. Finally, I used the SWFLoader from Spark.